# Powershell Regex replace

Tags: regex, powershell

Team,

I have a file in Windows where the content is like the below:

> 460  ls
>
> 461  cd ..
>
> 462  ls
>
> 463  cd ubuntu/
>
> 464  ls
>
> 465  cd test/
>
> 466  ls
>
> 467  cd ..
>
> 468  openvpn

I want to remove all the numbers which are present in the beginning and get the actual content.

I have tried :

```
$var= Get-Content C:\Scripts\test.txt
$var.replace("/[4 6]/","");

$var.replace("/[4 6]/","");

($var.replace("4","")).Replace("6","")
```

But is it possible to get some regular expression solution for this.

Comment: `$var -replace '^[\s\d]+',''`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Smaller : `$var -replace '^[\s\d]+'` (no need to add the second argument with `-replace` if it's a removal)

Comment: @Manu Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**When processing a file line by line** you may use the following pattern:

```
$var -replace '^[\s\d]+'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OaoD1X/1)

**When processing a whole file as one string** you would need to use

```
$var -replace '(?m)^[\p{Zs}\t\d]+'
```

in order not to overflow across lines. See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%5B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Ct%5Cd%5D%2B&i=460%20ls%0D%0A461%20cd%20..%0D%0A462%20ls%0D%0A463%20cd%20ubuntu%2F%0D%0A464%20ls%0D%0A465%20cd%20test%2F%0D%0A466%20ls%0D%0A467%20cd%20..%0D%0A468%20openvpn).

**Details**

- `^` - start of the input (when `(?m)` is used at the start of the pattern, `^` matches start of input and start of each line)
- `[\s\d]+` - one or more whitespaces (`\s`) or digits (`\d`)
- `[\p{Zs}\t]` - matches any horizontal whitespace.

[image]

Comment: @RanadipDutta: Sorry, I meant `(?m)^[\p{Zs}\t\d]+` of course, mixed up `\s` and `\d`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Worked neatly. Both of them . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using the following regular expression.

```
$result = $var -replace '^[\s]?\d+'
```

To update the file with the `$result` you can use the code below.

```
Set-Content -Value $result -Path C:\Scripts\test.txt
```

Comment: `$var -replace '^\d+'` is not working. It gave me the same output

Comment: @RanadipDutta when I execute $var -replace '^\d+' it returns the content without numbers as you asked for. To update the content of the file you have to assign the result to a variable like I did (i.e. `result`). Afterwards the content of the file has to be overriden by using the second statement I posted into my answer.

Comment: I did that. But that regex is not working. That I tried even earlier also.

Comment: @RanadipDutta do your lines in the text file start with a space?

Comment: The reason why it is not working is because I have leading spaces which you are not covering. I have mentioned that in the question. It is working with `'^[\s\d]+'`

Comment: @RanadipDutta I prefer to make handle leading spaces optionally. I updated the regular expression in my answer accordingly.

Comment: Fine. I saw that. But Wiktor's answer was the one i was looking for that time.